# "In Folge kommt es zu …" – oder "infolge", oder ausschließlich "infolgedessen"?

Tags: spelling, reference-request

Folgende Passage schien mir nicht falsch:

> […] wird eine solche Politik gewählt; **in Folge** kommt es zu einer Umverteilung von Steuergeldern […]

Eine andere mir zugetragene muttersprachliche Meinung dazu ist jedoch, dass es entweder *infolgedessen* oder *in der Folge* heißen müsste. Eine Recherche – auch hinsichtlich der weiteren sich aufdrängenden Frage, ob es eventuell *infolge* heißen müsste – ergab:

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/infolge) und [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/infolge) kennen *infolge* nur als Präposition, nicht jedoch als Konjunktionaladverb (wie *folglich*). Der [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/infolge_anlaesslich_aufgrund) kennt zwar ein Adverb *infolge*, jedoch ausschließlich »in Verbindung mit ›von‹«.

Bei der Suche nach *in Folge* erhält man als Ergebnis zunächst viele Varianten von *zum x-ten Mal in Folge*. Schränkt man die Suche daher beispielsweise auf den Ausdruck [*in Folge kommt es*](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22in+folge+kommt+es%22) ein, erhält man erstaunlich viele Fundstellen aus dem medizinischen Bereich, etwa:

> - In Folge kommt es zu einem komplexen chemischen Vorgang […] ([5](https://www.sanatorium-kettenbruecke.at/ambulanzen-ordinationen/wirbelsaeulenzentrum/wirbelsaeulenerkrankungen.html))
> - In Folge kommt es zu einer enzymatischen Fehlreaktion, […] ([6](https://www.lungeninformationsdienst.de/krankheiten/weitere-lungenerkrankungen/index.html))
> - In Folge kommt es zu massiven Verspannungen der Kau-, Gesichts- und Kopfmuskulatur […] ([7](https://www.gzfa.de/diagnostik-therapie/cmd-craniomandibulaere-dysfunktion/okklusion-in-der-zahnmedizin/))
> - In Folge kommt es zur Vasodilatation […] ([8](https://books.google.de/books?id=jgSnBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150))
> - In Folge kommt es zum Anstieg der Oxalsäure. ([9](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperoxalurie))
> - u.v.m.

Die Suche nach ***infolge** kommt es*, also zusammengeschrieben, liefert weniger Fundstellen, jedoch zeigt sich überraschend, dass das DWDS unter dem Stichwort [*leichtfüßig*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/leichtfl%C3%BCssig#d-1-1) dann doch noch ein (ausgerechnet medizinisches) Beispiel dafür verzeichnet, allerdings aus einem *Books-on-Demand*-Verlag:

> Infolge kommt es häufig zu Entzündungen der Luftwege.

Im Zusammenhang mit Luftwegen stellt auch das [Auswärtige Amt](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/aussenpolitik/laender/belarus-node/belarussicherheit/201904#content_0) fest:

> Infolge kommt es zu Einschränkungen im Flugverkehr mit Belarus.

Unstreitig gibt es daneben noch *infolgedessen*, jedoch geht es hier speziell um *in Folge* oder *infolge* als eigenständige Ausdrücke.

---

Nun bin ich verwirrt:

1. Offenbar gibt es den Ausdruck *infolge/in Folge [kommt es …]* ja, entgegen der o.g. Meinung. Welche Schreibweise ist dann aber richtig? Handelt es sich um ein selbstständiges Adverb oder um einen mehrteiligen Ausdruck? Gibt es hierzu irgendwo einen Wörterbucheintrag?
2. Wird der Ausdruck tatsächlich weit überwiegend im medizinischen Bereich genutzt oder ist das ein Artefakt der Internetsuche?

Comment: *infolge* bei der Lungenentzündung und dem Flugverkehr halte ich für ganz einfach falsch. Es müsste dort "in Folge" heißen. Das ist mMn eine falsche Verwendung einer Präposition (Es stellt sich sofort die Frage "wessen?").

Comment: Und meiner Meinung nach ist "in der Folge" wesentlich verbreiteter als nur "in Folge".

Comment: @KilianFoth Das dürfte drauf ankommen, wo man schaut. In juristischen, medizinischen und Verwaltungsdokumenten ist das Weglassen des Artikels wohl eher üblich. Überall sonst wohl eher nicht.

Answer (score 3):

*[infolge](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/infolge)* (Präposition) ist ein kausaler Zusammenhang. (A folgt aus B)

*[infolgedessen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/infolgedessen)* (Adverb, entstanden aus Präposition + Pronomen) ist ebenfalls ein kausaler Zusammenhang. (A folgt aus B)

*[in Folge](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_Folge)* (Wortverbindung) ist ein temporaler Zusammenhang (A folgt nach B).

Die Links verweisen nach Wiktionary, die Erklärungen entsprechen auch meinem eigenen Sprachgefühl.

Deine Beispiele, in denen eine Präposition als Adverb verwendet wird, halte ich ganz einfach für falsch.

Comment: Zusammengefasst würdest du also sagen, der temporale Ausdruck *in Folge* (''subsequently', laut leo.org übrigens *in **der** Folge*) wird auseinander- und nicht zusammengeschrieben. Nun wäre es schön, Belege dafür zu finden, denn das ist gerade die Schwierigkeit. Bei *eine Präposition als Adverb verwendet wird* gehe ich nicht ganz mit, denn es ist ja kein Gesetz, dass die zusammengeschriebene Variante eine Präposition sein *muss* – genauso gut könnte *infolge* eben ein Adverb sein. Daher der *reference-request* für *infolge* oder *in Folge*. Bleibt die Frage nach der medizinischen Verwendung.

Comment: @amadeusamadeus Nein. Hier gehts mAn nicht um die Auseinander- oder Zusammenschreibung von „in“ und „Folge“ sondern viel einfacher um drei verschiedene Wörter, die zufällig buchstabengleich sind und drei verschiedene Wörterbucheinträge haben. Das reicht mir eigentlich als Beleg.

Comment: Wenn man mich fragte, ob “Ball” jetzt das runde Ding aus Gummi oder eine Tanzveranstaltung sei, würden mir die zwei Wörterbucheinträge ja auch als Beleg ausreichen.

Comment: @Bodo Autsch. Danke - repariert.